# How to check how many subscribers are in data filter?

Tags: exacttarget

I'm starting to use data filters in Exact Target and wonder how to check how many subscribers satisfy set criteria for data filter.

Answer (score 0):

Likely the easiest way is to use the filters to create a filtered list (group) or a filtered data extension using the data filters you have created.  This can be refreshed(with Automation Studio groups can be automatically refreshed) to show you the exact number of applicable subscribers.

Outside that, I think there is some SQL that can pull using data filters or AMPscript/SSJS potentially, depending on how you wanted it and what you wanted to use it for.